Do generalized linear models really need to assume the distribution of errors?
A GLM has the following form:
$$
g(\mathbb E[Y\mathop | X])=X^T\beta
$$
where $g$ is the link function. We can write the moment conditions as
$$
Y=g^{-1}(X^T\beta)+\varepsilon,\\
\mathbb E[X^T\varepsilon]=0,
$$
the sample analog of which gives us the GMM estimator:
$$
\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^T[Y_i-g^{-1}(X_i^T\hat\beta_{\text{GMM}})]=0.
$$
Here's something I don't understand: many online sources say that the GLM requires specifying the distribution of the error term (e.g. Gaussian, Poisson, binomial, etc.), but is it really an assumption needed for the GLM to be valid? When a function $g$ is specified, we only need the moment conditions for the GMM estimator to be valid (which is true when the model is correctly specified, that is, $\mathbb E[\varepsilon \mathop |X]=0$, and even when the model is misspecified, we still get a "best parametric predictor" that approximates the "real" $\mathbb E[Y\mathop | X]$). So why is the error distribution often assumed in a GLM?

Answer of mine to a possibly related question

I’m not convinced that this is a duplicate, due to the specification of generalized method of moments estimation.

I am confused by the setting, because this appears to describe a very special GLM--it's certainly not a general formulation.  In fact, I cannot make mathematical sense of "$g^{-1}(X)^T.$"  Typo?

Assumptions are needed for inference, i.e., tests and confidence intervals. Your estimator may work well without such assumptions, but then you can't specify statistically how well.
